# Random Variables examples clarification

Tags: probability, random-variables

Just need some clarification as to whether these examples are correct.

Discrete random variables: 
If w (omega) is a set of books, let X be the discrete random variable representing the number of w (omega) we choose.

If w (omega) is a set of polygons, let X be the discrete random variable representing the number of w (omega) with less than 6 sides we choose.

Continuous random variables:
If w (omega) is a set of polygons, let X be the continuous random variable representing the angle in degrees of w (omega)

Thanks

Comment: To make Greek letter $\omega,$ type `$\omega$`.

Answer (score 0):

We define random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$, with $\Omega$ the space, $\mathcal{A}$ a $\sigma$-algebra on the space $\Omega$ and $\mathbb{P}$ a probability measure associated to the space and $\sigma$-algebra.

Usually $\Omega$ is not defined, but I understand that here, you seek to explicity define $\Omega$ to gain insight about random variables. A random variable $X$ is a function from $\Omega$ to a space $M$.

In the first example, if $\Omega$ is a set of books, then $X$ is a function of the book. Therefore you would measure the probability of an attribute of the selected books by $X$. If you meant $\Omega$ is a set of sets of books, so $\omega$ is a set of books, it does make sense. The other one is fine as well. You need to precise what the "angle in degrees of polygon" means to you concerning the last one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So if you were given this question, how would you answer it?                                                                                                     Let the sample space be a set of polygons. Give examples of
(i) a discrete random variable on the sample space; (ii) a continuous random variable on the sample space.

Comment: That's what I thought, the interpretation of $\Omega$  was wrong.
The sample space $\Omega$ is a set containing polygons, so your random variable $X$ is a function of the polygons.

i)  So I would say $X(\omega)$ is the number of sides of the polygon $\omega$.

ii) In this case, I could choose that $X(\omega)$ is the perimeter of $\omega$.